# JQuery select box loop with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried to use what was put in the JQuery Select Box and Loop Help question but it seems my implementation is a little different and I cannot seem to make it work.

I have a fromSelectBox and a toSelectBox that I am trying to move options around in.  There are two conditions I am trying to setup.   If option A is placed into the toSelectBox side it should always be at the bottom.  If option B is already on the toSelectBox side A should not be allowed to be moved.

I was able to make it so I cannot move option A or B from the bottom of the list, and I cannot move anything below A or B, however when I move a group of items over at once the order can be disturbed.

Basically what I want to do is any time a item is moved from the fromSelectBox, to the toSelect box that it should loop through and resort if necessary.

Here is what I have so far.

```
function resortOnMove() {
    $('select').each(function(){
       $('option', this).each(function(){
        if ($('#toSelectBox option:selected').val() == '03' || $('#toSelectBox option:selected').val() == '01') {
           alert("moving now");
            if ($('#toSelectBox option:selected').index() < $('#toSelectBox option:last').index()) {
               $('#toSelectBox option:selected').insertAfter($('#toSelectBox option:last'));
          }
       }
       })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that rather than doing a re-sort that it would be better to append the value at the end when adding multiples.

```
   $('#moveright').click(function () {
    var tempObjects = null;
    $('#fromSelectBox option:selected').each(function () {
        if (($('#toSelectBox option:last').val() == "03" || $('#toSelectBox option:last').val() == "01") && ($('#fromSelectBox option:selected').val() == "03" || $('#fromSelectBox option:selected').val() == "01")) {
            alert($('#toSelectBox option:last').text() + " and " + $('#fromSelectBox option:selected').text() + " cannot both be in Prioritized Categories.");
            return false
        }
        else if ($('#toSelectBox option:last').val() == "03" || $('#toSelectBox option:last').val() == "01") {
                var movingObjects = $(this);
                movingObjects.remove();
                movingObjects.insertBefore($('#toSelectBox option:last'));
        }
        else {
            $('#fromSelectBox option:selected').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === "01" || $(this).val() === "03") {
                    if (tempObjects!=null){
                        alert(tempObjects.text()+ " and " + $(this).text() + " cannot both be in Prioritized Categories.");
                        return false
                    }
                    tempObjects = $(this);
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                $(this).remove().appendTo('#toSelectBox');
            });
            if (tempObjects != null) {
                tempObjects.appendTo('#toSelectBox');
            }
        }
    });
});
```